# Joomla 2.5 manifest xml file is ignored

Tags: php, xml, joomla, joomla2.5

This is the content of my install directory (zip)

```
site
    controllers
    language
    models
    views
    ciie.php
    controller.php
    index.html
admin
    sql
    models
    language
    helpers
    controllers
    tables
    views
    ciie.php
    controller.php
    ciie.xml
    index.html  
ciie.xml
media
index.html
```

And here is my manifest xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="component" version="2.5.0" method="upgrade">

<name>CIIE</name>
<creationDate></creationDate>
<author></author>
<authorEmail></authorEmail>
<authorUrl></authorUrl>
<copyright></copyright>
<license></license>
<version></version>
<description></description>

<install> <!-- Runs on install -->
    <sql>
        <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/install.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
    </sql>
</install>

<files folder="site">
        <folder>controllers</folder>
        <folder>language</folder>
        <folder>models</folder>
        <folder>views</folder>
        <filename>ciie.php</filename>
        <filename>controller.php</filename>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
</files>

<media destination="com_ciie" folder="media">
    <filename>index.html</filename>
    <folder>images</folder>
</media>

<administration>
    <menu img="../media/com_ciie/images/tux-16x16.png">CIIE</menu>
    <files folder="admin">
            <folder>sql</folder>
            <folder>models</folder>
            <folder>language</folder>
            <folder>helpers</folder>
            <folder>controllers</folder>
            <folder>tables</folder>
            <folder>views</folder>
            <filename>ciie.php</filename>
            <filename>controller.php</filename>
            <filename>index.html</filename>
    </files>
</administration>

</extension>
```

The problem is after installing some of the folders are not properly copied to component directories
Here is what I got after install

```
Front end (site)
com_ciie
    views
    ciie.php
    controller.php
    index.html
Backend (Administrator)
    ciie.xml
    index.html
    ciie.php
```

Then I changed the manifest xml file to see if my xml has a problem. I removed all the folder tags

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="component" version="2.5.0" method="upgrade">

<name>CIIE</name>
<creationDate></creationDate>
<author></author>
<authorEmail></authorEmail>
<authorUrl></authorUrl>
<copyright></copyright>
<license></license>
<version></version>
<description></description>

<install> <!-- Runs on install -->
    <sql>
        <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/install.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
    </sql>
</install>

<files folder="site">
        <filename>ciie.php</filename>
        <filename>controller.php</filename>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
</files>

<media destination="com_ciie" folder="media">
    <filename>index.html</filename>
    <folder>images</folder>
</media>

<administration>
    <menu img="../media/com_ciie/images/tux-16x16.png">CIIE</menu>
    <files folder="admin">
            <filename>ciie.php</filename>
            <filename>controller.php</filename>
            <filename>index.html</filename>
    </files>
</administration>

</extension>
```

But The same folder structure is repeated in the component directories
Here is what I got after install

```
Front end (site)
com_ciie
    views
    ciie.php
    controller.php
    index.html
Backend (Administrator)
    ciie.xml
    index.html
    ciie.php
```

As you can see the second mainfiest file doesn't include any folder (all folder tags are removed) but 'views' folder is copied in the front end! What it seems for me is that the manifest file doesn't have any effect on the 'broken' installation. Did I miss anything?

Comment: have you had a problem installing any other extensions, or is it just your one?

Comment: @lodder only in this one. I followed the same procedure for my other components and they worked fine. But for this one, the same problem repeats itself in different joomla installations. I used the 'discover' feature to install the component without a problem. I just can't use the manifest file. Thanks.

Comment: You have two copies of ciie.xml in your package, one in the root and the other in admin; you should only keep the one in the root, it will be copied to the admin directory by the installer. And it will make debugging easier (in your second run without the folders you still get the "views" frontend folder which is not specified in the xml, I guess it's using the wrong one!

Comment: Thank you sooo much @RiccardoZorn If you posted it as an answer I would accept it! That's solved my 2 days problem!

Comment: glad it helped, I posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two copies of ciie.xml in your package, one in the root and the other in admin; you should only keep the one in the root, it will be copied to the admin directory by the installer. And it will make debugging easier (in your second run without the folders you still get the "views" frontend folder which is not specified in the xml, I guess it's using the wrong one!

Answer (score -3):

Try and recreate the structure using [Joomla Component Creator](http://www.component-creator.com) and then see what the difference is in the manifest file.

Make sure to update the question as I am curious now.

Comment: You should post such a hint in a comment instead of pretending to answer that question with something unsure and guessing...